# Puppy full of ticks

Tags: dogs, parasites, ticks

[image]

This is what I removed from my 6 week old puppy. I believe it's a tick. 20 have been removed so far. The puppy still has more. The internet suggested removing them with tweezers. But the puppy is under extreme discomfort and doesn't want to be held down. Morever, he cries a lot and just doesn't let us do it. We've tried treats and toys but they just don't work. Is there any way to get rid of them that is easier for the puppy?

Comment: If it's not done properly, parts of the ticks can remain embedded in the dogs skin and can cause infections. It may be better to take the dog to a vet. You also need to discover the source of the ticks and keep the dog away from wherever they are.

Comment: See also this answer for removal tips: [How to remove a tick on a dog?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/2553/9069) It doesn't address the unhappy puppy factor, tho.

Comment: With so many ticks on such a young puppy, I think there's a good chance he's anemic now. That's another reason (in addition to what Mick said) for taking him to the vet. Especially if his gums are pale.

Answer (score 4):

Side note: Im in the woods with my 8 year old Yella Lab every morning at sunup for an hour.  We used to use one of those topical tick/flea oils,  but switched to Trifexis about 5 years ago, because he's a swimmer.  Tick checks daily.  With the oils, I pulled a little more than 2 ticks a week off him.  Since the switch, it's less than half that.  A few times a year I miss one, and have to snatch one of those gross and bloated blobs off him.

After his first annual, I decided to have a Lyme disease shot added, which I have continued throughout his life.  The extra layer of protection is nice.

Answer (score 3):

He's likely anxious because he doesn't know what is going on. He might also be taking his cues from you if you are worrying while removing them. Keep breathing. Talk to him in a reassuring voice. Take breaks in between removals. Give him affection (rather than treats) and move slowly. Check him thoroughly all over - there's nowhere they won't settle in for a meal. Check the ears, in between toes, his butthole: all of him.

You might consider something like a "[tick twister](https://youtu.be/zZal4GTRG4k)." For what it is worth, I've lived with outdoor dogs and tick checks were a daily routine. Tweezers can work, but if the ticks are large enough, I just pull them by hand. You do want to make sure that you completely get the entire head out, otherwise the skin can get infected.

Note that there are "Deer ticks" and "Dog ticks". "Deer ticks" are the smaller ones with the red pouches. "Dog ticks" are the bigger ones with dark brown pouches that have a white marking. [Here's a guide for telling which kind](http://health.westchestergov.com/tick-borne-diseases/deer-tick-identification).

Deer ticks are the ones that carry [lyme disease](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/), so be wary and wash your hands and instruments after getting rid of them. I am told by vets and my doctors that to get lime disease from a tick, it usually needs to be attached to a human for 48-72 hours. A bite does not mean you've gotten lime disease, but it pays to be safe!

Your vet should be able to tell you when it is usually "tick season" in your area. I've always noticed them more of a problem right after it rains and the ground is wet. They'll crawl up onto long blades of grass and hop on passers-by.

Lastly, it'd be good to check in with your vet about puppy shampoo, something for the skin where be was bit, and, puppy approved tick repellant options. [Lyme disease in dogs is also an issue](https://www.mspca.org/angell_services/lyme-disease-in-dogs/), so do check in with your vet regarding what to be wary of such as lameness, fever, lethargy, and enlarged lymph nodes. As I understand tho, a deer tick with Lyme disease needs to be attached to the dog for 48hrs for the transmission of the disease.

I don't know that your dog is necessarily in pain from the bites. A tick bite does hurt when they bite a human. It can be a sharp pain, but some people don't notice. Dogs have very different skin than humans too, but, no matter what, consult your vet about remediation, prevention and detecting lyme disease and how to avoid ticks in the future. Hope your puppy feels better soon!

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply flea/tick treatment to skin and I suggest Frontline plus
every one month

> FRONTLINE Plus has 2 secret weapons: fipronil and (S)-methoprene. Once
>   FRONTLINE Plus is applied, this combo stores itself in the oil glands
>   in your pet's skin. It then self-distributes continuously for 1 month
>   to your pet's hair and skin through the hair follicles. Fleas or ticks
>   that come in contact with your pet are dead meat.
>   [Source - frontline.com](https://frontline.com/plus/Pages/Faq.aspx)

Note: many youtube videos describe how to use the topical treatment on pets its very easy

Your vet may suggest using an annual dose of Ivermectin

> 6 ug/kg for heartworm prevention 300 ug/kg for treatment of sarcoptic
>   mange 400-600 ug/kg for treatment of demodectic mange. [Source - petmd.com](https://www.petmd.com/blogs/fullyvetted/2013/jan/toxic-ivermectin-and-safe-use-of-ivermectin-29671)

Which is very important to protect your puppy from another infection which may come with ticks and fleas.

---

Update: 
As requested, a reference from [WebMD](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/ticks-lyme-disease-dogs#2) pet section topical treatment as mentioned above is recommended and it's easy to be applied by pet owners.

reference for a well-known brand name topical treatment [MERCK Animal Health](https://www.merck-animal-health.com/species/companion-animals/index.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up for anyone else looking to cure a puppy from ticks. Since most tick repellents could have adverse effects on a puppy it might be a good idea to use a topical agent such as diatomaceous earth. Check out this [fact sheet](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/degen.html) and this article by [Dr.Axe](https://draxe.com/diatomaceous-earth/)

Comment: please consider expanding this answer,as it is now it is close to a link only answer.if you put in some of the main points from the links it will make your answer better.

Comment: We currently have more than [20 posts about diatomaceous earth](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=diatomaceous+), answer that are heavily dependent on exteranl links are discouraged as these lose value when the links die.  Can you update your answer to link to answers on Pets.SE? You may also want to consider contributing to one the existing questions about diatomaceous earth

Answer (score -3):

Ugh ticks are terrible!!! I tend to try and treat my animals as naturally as possible. SO far this summer I have been using Dogs Naturally's all [natural tick repellent](https://www.dogsnaturallymagazine.com/why-flea-and-tick-products-are-a-bad-idea-and-4-natural-repellent-recipes/). I can say that so far is it has worked amazingly well. I would recommend trying some of these recipes before you give anything from the store to your dog. These are gentle and you can rub them into your puppy without scaring him with a spray or a pill. The essential oil is what I use and my dog loves it.,

I recommend that you avoid the harsh chemicals for flea/tick preventatives like [Nexgard](http://dogthusiast.com/2015/04/30/examining-insecticides-afoxolaner-and-fluralaner-as-used-in-flea-and-tick-preventatives/). A lot of people have experienced bad reactions from their dogs and even death. The good news is that there are so many natural tick repellents that actually do work.

Comment: I am not sure this is an answer to this question, in any case the question [Why all the safety concerns regarding topical flea products?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/why-all-the-safety-concerns-regarding-topical-flea-products) might be where you want to post what you are trying to say.  Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to help you create an answer that will be better accepted.